# Error: undefined method 'attribute' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array in Ruby by the objects' attribute, but I think that this line of code operates on nil elements in the array.

```
@my_array.sort_by {|object| object.attribute}
```

How do I make sure that methods called on my array do not call methods on nil elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "indexes are empty"? You are directly iterating over the array, and are not using index at all. You should not need to worry whether a certain index points to an element in the array or not.

Comment: @sawa: by "empty indexes" he probably means "nil elements"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Maybe you are right. It is bad habit of the OP to just randomly put information in the title without any explanation, isolated from the text.

Comment: The error was caused by nil elements in the array like Sergio pointed out, but I wasn't sure since I'm new to Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [compact](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-compact-21) array before sorting (this will remove nil elements)

```
sorted_arr = @my_array.compact.sort_by {|object| object.attribute}
```

Also, here's a shortcut for this specific case

```
sorted_arr = @my_array.compact.sort_by(&:attribute)
```